# create new column on dataset clojure

Tags: data-binding, clojure

I need help with formatting data in clojure.

I am reading data into a clojure script from an Oracle DB with this query

SELECT location, time, date FROM centralEventTable WHERE time BETWEEN 12/08/2013 and 14/08/2013

> the data from the result set called "Result" is then being used to get a Map of all location's like so;

(map (keyword :location) Result)

I then need to loop through the location names, create a new column called ApplicationName and assign an application name to each tuple based on the data contained in location.

The data I want to be able to present in a table format is ApplicationName, Location, Time and Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have a function called `application-name` that takes a location cell as input and returns an ApplicationName cell, you can do this:

```
(map (fn [{:keys [location] :as row}]
       (assoc row
              :ApplicationName (application-name location)))
     Result)
```

P.S.: For the first line of your question

```
(map :location Result)
```

should be enough, since :location already is a keyword. Also, capitalized names are usually used for types and interfaces, so I'd recommend to call it `result`.

```
(map :location result) ;; most idiomatic.
```